# Popping up a bootstrap model in a Knockout Foreach

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm attempting to show the user a modal while using Knockout, it seems like whenever it is called from within the foreach, the modal does not work or in the case of a hardcoded link, the contents open in a new page instead of popping out a modal.

Have a look at the fiddle below, the button on line 32 looks like it ignores the click whereas the button on line 37 works as it should

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="modal:showDialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-bind="click : submit">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table>

  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: SearchOptions" class="table">
    <tr class="gridRowSelect">

      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: function(){showDialog(true)}">Show</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: function(){showDialog(true)}">Show</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/slipmatt/ckuqrrnn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix the `showDialog` with the `$parent` keyword to provide proper [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){$parent.showDialog(true)}">Show</button>
```

Inside the `foreach` binding, knockout looks for `showDialog` inside each `AttributeKey` object rather than the `AttributeViewModel` instance. You can prefix it with `$root` as well, since in this case `$parent` and `$root` refer to the `AttributeViewModel` instance.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ckuqrrnn/3/)

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser console, you'll see an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined

This is because the first button is within a `foreach` binding, and so is looking for the `showDialog` function to exist on the `AttributeKey` item itself.  You instead need to point it to the parent context:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){$parent.showDialog(true)}">Show</button>
```

Since the parent is also the root model, you can use that too:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){$root.showDialog(true)}">Show</button>
```

This is useful in cases where you have multiple nested bindings and need to go directly back to your root model.